# Setup replication from one local disk to another local disk ( Ubuntu )

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, lvm, replication, ssd

Is there is are some way to setup local replication of the one disk to the another ( Ubuntu ) in the such way that all read operations will be involve only first disk ? Such configuration will be very usefull for AWS SSD instances. In this case SSD instance storage ( which is non-persistent disk and will be erased after instance stopped ) can be replicated to the EBS disk. When using such configuration data intensive services ( like MySQL or MongoDB ) can be configured to use SSD disk and in the same time we can ensure that data will be permanently stored in the EBS.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create `md` device in RAID1 mode where the read operations are  issued to the faster device preferably

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 --write-mostly /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

where the device `/dev/sdb` is slower for reading (e.g. SATA drive) while the `/dev/sdc` is performing better (e.g. SSD drive). The configuration above means the drive `/dev/sdc` will be avoided for reading.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called bcache: http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/

It writes and reads from the faster device, while periodically writing to the slower one

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

dd command can copy disk in raw format. It will copy partition table and bootloader and all partitions within this disk.

if=/dev/sda : Input disk (source)

of=/dev/sdb : Output disk (destination)

Comment: You should at least tell him what does that do